# What is the influence of the measurement offset in the PI control loop?

Tags: control-system, pid-controller

Let's say I have a control loop with a direct acting PI controller

[image]

Now suppose that there is some positive offset present on the measurment of the controlled variable and at the same time the reference value of the controlled variable is zero. My expectation is that at the steady state the controller output i.e. the action will be at the value \$u_{max} - \Delta u\$, where the \$\Delta u\$ is caused by integration of the offset in the integration part of the controller. Is my expectation correct?

Comment: It all depends on how the clipping block works.

Answer (score 1):

If I read it right, R is constant. If it's not, this is not an answer.

If G has such dynamics that PI control principle can generate right stable output, which is not prevented by the clipping of U and the offset is a constant or depends on Y monotonically, there's a stable output error = the measurement offset. What's then U, it's what's needed for R+measurement offset (as said, assuming the clipping allows the needed U)

The behaviour becomes hard to predict if the offset is not constant, but depends on the changing direction of Y or depends on Y non-monotonically.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. Yes, the \$R\$ is constant. I am sorry if I am wrong but my understanding of your answer is that it basically confirms my expectation.

Comment: Your expectation is not good. You should see it even in case there's no measurement error. Assume G is a DC motor which needs 41 volts input to reach the wanted r.p.m, which is now given as voltage R. Let's assume a) U is limited to 40 volts. The wanted r.p.m is never reached. U stops to 40 volts. b) U is limited to 100 volts. The wanted r.p.m. is reached and U settles to 41 volts.